# how to update text value in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two screen, I added text on 1st screen and if I edit that text then I have click on menuItem edit button its goes to 2nd screen and found 1st screen value in TextInput field I edit and update value to the screen 1st??

can any one please help me??

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the value in your route as follow :

`navigate('yourpath', {yourParam: paramValue});`

This way you can get `yourParams` this way :

`const { yourParam } = route.params;`

Here is the link [to the doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params) that explain it well.

Comment: here I get the value of params 
 render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    let update = navigation.getParam('post')

but how I update this update variable value with my exiting text

Comment: If you need your modification to replicate from screen 1 to screen 2 and vice versa, i think you should use a context and dispatch the value, it will be way easier to handle. I don't think you can replicate your value from your screen 2 back to your screen 1 without it